# Can you hide date field when its date matches with the sites date?

Tags: entities, rules, datetime

I have a date field in my site and I want it to hide/be invisible when the date I have set is now or matches the sites date.
I hope there is a way to do this using Rules.

Comment: What do you mean by the site's date? The current date/time in the site's timezone?

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, but never mind I found that I can do it in an easier way using Field formatter conditions.


If anyone in the future sees this and wants to know how, Go to Manage Display, go to the field, click on the settings thing, open Conditions, and choose Hide date/time and it'll give you the options you want.

Comment: I feel like the conditions setting you are referring to are provided by another module, not part of basic field functionality, like maybe the field formatter conditions module.

Comment: Yea It works with Field Formatter Conditions module, but there is a problem is that it doesn't match with the sites Timezone which is weird, the site's time zone is +10 (Australia) and the field gets hidden 10 hours before the actual time that is set in the field.

So I hope there is way to fix this.

Comment: Looks like the field formatter conditions module doesn't properly handle timezones. You should open an issue in that module's issue queue asking for improved timezone handling for the hide date/time condition.

Comment: I figured it out, it's because of the 'Time zone handling setting'.  [Great explanation here on how they work.](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3613/the-differences-between-date-time-zone-handling)

Comment: Ah, so your field wasn't set to use site's timezone?

Comment: I know it is slightly different but this is kind of a duplciate of [Can I hide date field if older than a certian time using Rules?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109848/can-i-hide-date-field-if-older-than-a-certian-time-using-rules)

Comment: It was set to the site's time zone, but in the explanation it says that when the date is saved to the database it is converted to UTC and converted back when retrieved from the database, so it seems like FFC was hiding it directly from the database so that's why it was hiding it in UTC, I changed it to No Time Zone Handling and it works properly.

Comment: That's the bug in the module I was talking about. You shouldn't have to set it to no timezone handling and setting it to that might cause you timezone problems in future, although that depends on your site and the field's use case.

Comment: I opened an issue https://drupal.org/node/2240123

Comment: Okay, great. I hope it gets fixed soon.